# Stream audio with AVAudioPlayer from a URL containing a utf8 encoded string

Tags: swift, utf-8, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I'm using a library named `KDEAudioPlayer`, I was initially streaming mp3 audio files with it and it was working perfectly. Now I'm trying to stream an `mp3` file encoded to `utf8` and it's broken.

The api returns a response that looks like this: `ID3DTPE1merssoTYER2018TSSEStudio One 3.5.4.45392`.
It's basically a normal `mp3` file encoded to `utf8`.

So is there any way I can stream that using `AVAudioPlayer`?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Now I'm trying to stream an mp3 file encoded to utf8" WHAT? This doesn't make sense at all. It's unclear. Ar you saying that the URL need to percent escape the invalid characters, like a space into %20 ?

Comment: I mean that the `KDEAudioPlayer` used to only take the url and it streamed the file just fine. That was because the link ended in `.mp3` and was a simple mp3 file. Now the link returns a utf-8 encoded version of that file. What can I do to decode it?

Comment: What do you mean by a " utf-8 encoded version of that file"? there are many binary values (255 for example) that can not be represented correctly in a utf8 string, unless you are using another encoding like base64. If you are converting a binary file to a utf8 string, you are corrupting it. Your question make no sense.